# Close a tkinter GUI after a period of time

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy

I want to create a GUI that shows a message and it is automatically destroyed after some time. I saw this question in different posts but none of the solutions proposed worked out for my App. Here a small part of the code

```
class MessageShort(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):

def __init__(self, parent, text, time):


    self.top=Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.transient(parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.text=text
    self.time=time
    body = Frame(self)
    self.initial_focus = self.body(body)
    body.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    if not self.initial_focus:
        self.initial_focus = self
    self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (parent.winfo_rootx()+200,
                              parent.winfo_rooty()+75))
    self.initial_focus.focus_set()
    self.wait_window(self)

def body(self, master):
    m=Message(master, text=self.text).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
    master.after(self.time,master.destroy())

MessageShort(root,"Select date and decimal format",2000)#call from another part to the class to create the GUI message

root = Tk()
app = App(root) #main App
root.mainloop()
```

The App have different Menus and Tkinter classes to display the different tools
With the current code I close the App and I just want to close the message but not the App

Comment: Why didn't these other solutions not work for you? What specifically did you try that didn't work?

Comment: remove `()` from `master.after(self.time,master.destroy())` so it looks like `master.after(self.time,master.destroy)` otherwise you are calling the destroy method straight away.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley you were right and quite close

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer and set destroying the root as it's callback:

```
from threading import Timer
import time

def called_after_timer():
  if(root != None):
    root.destroy()

t = Timer(20 * 60, called_after_timeout)
t.start()

# do something else, such as
time.sleep(1500)
```

Comment: root can not be destroy otherwise the App is closed

Comment: Then hide the root window: call: 'root.withdraw()' then call 'newWin = Toplevel()' This will create a window that isn't the root. Therefore the root will still be running in the mainloop even after the second window is closed. Make sure to call root.destroy() somewhere though, otherwise the program never exits.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got something that seems to work

class MessageShort(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):

```
    def __init__(self, parent, text, time):


        self.top=Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.transient(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.text=text
        self.time=time
        body = Frame(self)
        self.initial_focus = self.body(body)
        body.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        if not self.initial_focus:
            self.initial_focus = self
        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (parent.winfo_rootx()+200,
                                parent.winfo_rooty()+75))
        self.initial_focus.focus_set()
        self.wait_window(self)

    def body(self, master):
        m=Message(master, text=self.text).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        master.after(self.time,self.destroy)

MessageShort(root,"Select date and decimal format",2000)#call from another part to the class to create the GUI message

root = Tk()
app = App(root) #main App
root.mainloop()
```

In the last line self.master.destroy destroys m but not the container itself. So it has to call to self.destroy